# addind a word in a prefix position throughout a file

Tags: function, file, variables, addition, prefix

I have a file with three column. I have to add a word to the second column in all the rows.
example,
column1 column2 column3
hello1  morning  bye
hello2  morning  bye
hello3  morning  bye

I need
column1 column2 column3
hello1  good_morning  bye
hello2  good_morning  bye
hello3  good_morning  bye

As I have to repeat the process for different files, I have $c = 'good_'.
How will I write it as a code.

I tried sed -e 's/^/'$c_'/' file.txt > file1.txt

so instead of writing good_ it writes $c_morning or just writes morning.